# Return status error to WebRequest

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, httpwebrequest

I call a remote action with a `WebRequest` like that:

```
var site = "http://remoteSite.com/controller/IsolateSite?url=xxx&target=in";
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(site);
var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

if (response.StatusDescription == "OK")
{ /* code */ }
else
{ /* code */ }
```

In the remote action, I return a message or `null` (if `id` is good or not).

But `response.StatusDescription` is always equal to `"OK"` even if the action returns `null`.

How can I force an error as status or retrieve a message (like `"Cool."` or `"Error."`)?

---

The remote action sample :

```
public static string IsolateSite(string url, string target)
{
    var serverManager = new ServerManager();
    var isHttps = url.Contains("https");
    var regex = new Regex("^(http|https)://");
    var host = regex.Replace(url, "");
    var instance = serverManager.Sites.First(site => site.Bindings.Any(binding => binding.Host == host));
    var pool = instance.Applications[0].ApplicationPoolName;

    if ((pool.Contains("isolation") && target == "out") || (!pool.Contains("isolation") && target == "in"))
    {
        return "Error."; //or return null but the status code is OK so useless
    }

    //etc...

    return "Cool.";
}
```

Comment: How does a sample action look like where you want to return an error case?

Comment: what is your response.StatusCode?

Comment: @Raj - OK (System.Net.HttpStatusCode)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Httpstatus codes like `error` or `cool` aren't valid, [here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) you can find all the status codes.

Instead of returning a string on error, the best you can do is throwing a HttpException:

```
throw new HttpException(500, "Error");
```

In this case I use http response status code 500 (Internal Server Error).

Another consideration is to look at ASP.NET WebApi for this kind of services, I think is suits better then an Asp.NET MVC controller.

Answer (score 0):

Just take the response to a StreamReader like given below.

```
      var site = "http://remoteSite.com/controller/action/id";
      var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(site);
      var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
      StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
       // This will contain the status of message e.g.    failed, ok etc.
      string resultStatus = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

The result status will give you the Error Status and Description